# Makefile does not find target

Tags: makefile, directory, target

I have the following Makefile, but it does not work. When I call

```
make html
```

I get a

```
make: *** No rule to make target `docs/index.html', needed by `html'.  Stop.
```

error, even though I think I have defined it.

```
SRCDIR = source
OUTDIR = docs

RMD = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.Rmd)

TMP  = $(RMD:.Rmd=.html)
HTML = ${subst $(SRCDIR),$(OUTDIR),$(TMP)}


test:
    echo $(RMD)
    echo $(TMP)
    echo $(HTML)


all: clean update html

html:   $(HTML)

%.html: %.Rmd
    echo $(HTML)
    @Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('$<', output_format = 'prettydoc::html_pretty', output_dir = './$(OUTDIR)/')"

update:
    @Rscript -e "devtools::load_all(here::here()); microcosmScheme:::updateFromGoogleSheet(token = './source/googlesheets_token.rds')"


## from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26339924/632423
list:
    @$(MAKE) -pRrq -f $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) : 2>/dev/null | awk -v RS= -F: '/^# File/,/^# Finished Make data base/ {if ($$1 !~ "^[#.]") {print $$1}}' | sort | egrep -v -e '^[^[:alnum:]]' -e '^$@$$' | xargs

.PHONY: update clean cleanhtml all list
```

The variables seem to be correct:

```
15:21 $ make test
echo source/index.Rmd
source/index.Rmd
echo source/index.html
source/index.html
echo docs/index.html
docs/index.html
```

If I change it as follow it works, but the target points to the SRCDIR, but I want it to point to the OUTDIR:

```
RMD = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.Rmd)

HTML  = $(RMD:.Rmd=.html)
# HTML = ${subst $(SRCDIR),$(OUTDIR),$(TMP)}
```

I am sure it is one small thing...

Comment: Is there a reason why you did not declare `help` as phony?

Comment: Do i have a ‚help‘ target?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `html` (I too frequently have a phony `help` target as my default goal).

Comment: That is exactly what I do not want. But thanks for pointing the=at option out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule:

```
%.html : %.Rmd
        ....
```

tells make how to build a file `foo.html` from a file `foo.Rmd`, or a file `source/foo.html` from a file `source/foo.Rmd`, or a file `docs/foo.html` from a file `docs/foo.Rmd`.

It doesn't tell make how to build a file `docs/foo.html` from a file `source/foo.Rmd`, because the stem that matches the pattern `%` is not the same.

If you want to write a pattern for `docs/foo.html` to be built from `source/foo.Rmd`, you have to write it like this:

```
$(OUTDIR)/%.html : $(SRCDIR)/%.Rmd
      ....
```

so that the part that matches the pattern `%` is identical.

*ETA* Some other notes: you should be using `:=` with the `wildcard` function as it's much better performing.  Also you shouldn't use `subst` here because it replaces *all* occurrences of the string which could break things if any of your `.Rmd` files contain the string `source` for example (e.g., `source/my_source_file.Rmd`.  This is much better written with `patsubst`, as in:

```
RMD := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.Rmd)
HTML := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.Rmd,$(OBJDIR)/%.html,$(RMD))
```

Finally, you don't show what the `clean` target does but it's unusual to have the `clean` target depended on by `all`.  Usually it's a separate target that is invoked only when you want it, like `make clean`.

Comment: Makes sense. But I now changed the Makefile as suggested, but I still get the same error. I posted it as a gist at https://gist.github.com/rkrug/f060bab62b3b0c1b20a7360e86cd0652

Comment: It's because I incorrectly used the variable `SOURCE` in my example pattern rule when the variable you used was `SRCDIR`, and you blindly copied my mistake :).  Unknown variables expand to the empty string so your pattern rule was `docs/%.html : /%.Rmd` which of course won't work.

Comment: Thanks. Workshop perfectly now.