# Installing reaction-platform on windows, getting error like `Parameter format not correct`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, reaction-commerce

I'm trying to install `reaction-platform` on my windows system. I have cofirmed the dependancies mentioned, everything seems fine.

I'm fllowing the official documentation.

https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/docs/installation-reaction-platform

When I run `make` command getting issue like:

> 28ec31dc0e9cba366bdbb724ce1f9733b327aae90801f371c234437748d7d688
>   abc5351b5c17853153771d8a9e868d4f443106bb908d23f6672531cd6105364c
>   dc796c6d02a715ccd9e1133157cb770e5399ed66184202186c1151d520e1d03b
>
> Running pre-build hook script for reaction-hydra. reaction-hydra
>
> post-project-start script invoked. FIND: Parameter format not correct
>
> make: *** [prebuild-reaction-hydra] Error 2

Here is the makefile:

```
#gnu makefile
# This Makefile provides macro control of the Reaction Platform microservice
# ecosystem. It performs tasks like:
#
#   * Verify dependencies are present
#   * Clone git projects, checkout a particular reference
#   * Preconfiguration and subproject bootstrapping
#   * Launching subprojects
#   * Teardown tasks with varying destructiveness
#
#
# Exit codes:
#
#   All failures should exit with a detailed code that can be used for
#   troubleshooting. The current exit codes are:
#
#     0: Success!
#   101: Github is not configured correctly.
#   102: Required dependency is not installed.
#

###############################################################################
### Configuration
### Load configuration from external files. Configuration variables defined in
### later files have precedent and will overwrite those defined in previous
### files. The -include directive ensures that no error is thrown if a file is
### not found, which is the case if config.local.mk does not exist.
###############################################################################
-include config.mk config.local.mk

SUBPROJECTS=$(foreach rr,$(SUBPROJECT_REPOS),$(shell echo $(rr) | cut -d , -f 2))


###############################################################################
### Tasks
###############################################################################
all: init

###############################################################################
### Init-Project
### Initializes a project. Does not do common tasks shared between projects.
###############################################################################
define init-template
init-$(1): $(1) network-create prebuild-$(1) build-$(1) post-build-$(1) start-$(1) post-project-start-$(1)
endef
$(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),$(eval $(call init-template,$(p))))

###############################################################################
### Init Project with System
### Init project and run the post-system hook script.
### Assumes dependencies are already started.
###############################################################################
define init-with-system-template
init-with-system-$(1): init-$(1) post-system-start-$(1)
endef
$(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),$(eval $(call init-with-system-template,$(p))))

.PHONY: init
init: $(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),init-$(p)) post-system-start

###############################################################################
### Targets to verify Github is configured correctly.
###############################################################################
github-configured: dependencies
    @(ssh -T git@github.com 2>&1 \
      | grep "successfully authenticated" >/dev/null \
      && echo "Github login verified.") \
    || (echo "You need to configure an ssh key with access to github" \
    && echo "See https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/ for instructions" \
    && exit 101)


###############################################################################
### Verify prerequisite software is installed.
###############################################################################
is-not-installed=! (command -v $(1) >/dev/null)

define dependency-template
dependency-$(1):
    @if ( $(call is-not-installed,$(1)) ); \
    then \
      echo "Dependency" $(1) " not found in path." \
      && exit 102; \
    else \
      echo "Dependency" $(1) "found."; \
    fi;
endef
$(foreach pkg,$(REQUIRED_SOFTWARE),$(eval $(call dependency-template,$(pkg))))

.PHONY: dependencies
dependencies: $(foreach pkg,$(REQUIRED_SOFTWARE),dependency-$(pkg))

###############################################################################
### Create Docker Networks
### Create all networks defined in the DOCKER_NETWORKS variable.
### Networks provide a way to loosely couple the projects and allow them to
### communicate with each other. We'll use dependencies on external networks
### rather than dependencies on other projects. Networks are lightweight and
### easy to create.
###############################################################################
define network-create-template
network-create-$(1):
    @docker network create "$(1)" || true
endef
$(foreach p,$(DOCKER_NETWORKS),$(eval $(call network-create-template,$(p))))

.PHONY: network-create
network-create: $(foreach p,$(DOCKER_NETWORKS),network-create-$(p))

###############################################################################
### Remove Docker Networks
### Remove all networks defined in the DOCKER_NETWORKS variable.
###############################################################################
define network-remove-template
network-remove-$(1):
    @docker network rm "$(1)" || true
endef
$(foreach p,$(DOCKER_NETWORKS),$(eval $(call network-remove-template,$(p))))

.PHONY: network-remove
network-remove: $(foreach p,$(DOCKER_NETWORKS),network-remove-$(p))

###############################################################################
### Git cloning
###############################################################################
define git-clone-template
$(2):
    if [ ! -d "$(2)" ] ; then \
      git clone "$(1)" "$(2)"; \
      cd $(2) && git checkout "$(3)"; \
    fi
endef
$(foreach rr,$(SUBPROJECT_REPOS),$(eval $(call git-clone-template,$(shell echo $(rr) | cut -d , -f 1),$(shell echo $(rr) | cut -d , -f 2),$(shell echo $(rr) | cut -d , -f 3))))

.PHONY: clone
clone: github-configured $(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),$(p))

###############################################################################
### Git checkout
### Checkout the branch configured in the platform settings.
### Does not gracefully deal with conflicts or other problems.
###############################################################################
define git-checkout-template
checkout-$(2): $(2)
    cd $(2) && git checkout "$(3)"
endef
$(foreach rr,$(SUBPROJECT_REPOS),$(eval $(call git-checkout-template,$(shell echo $(rr) | cut -d , -f 1),$(shell echo $(rr) | cut -d , -f 2),$(shell echo $(rr) | cut -d , -f 3))))

.PHONY: checkout
checkout: clone $(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),checkout-$(p))

###############################################################################
### Pre Build Hook
### Invokes the pre-build hook in the child project directory if it exists.
### Invoked before the Docker Compose build.
###############################################################################
define prebuild-template
prebuild-$(1): $(1)
    @if [ -e "$(1)/$(HOOK_DIR)/pre-build" ]; then \
      echo "Running pre-build hook script for $(1)." \
      && "$(1)/$(HOOK_DIR)/pre-build"; \
    else \
      echo "No pre-build hook script for $(1). Skipping."; \
    fi;
endef
$(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),$(eval $(call prebuild-template,$(p))))

.PHONY: prebuild
prebuild: $(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),prebuild-$(p))


###############################################################################
### Docker Build
### Performs `docker-compose build --no-cache --pull`
### This is a very conservative build strategy to avoid cache related build
### issues.
###############################################################################
define build-template
build-$(1): prebuild-$(1)
    @cd $(1) \
      && docker-compose build --no-cache --pull
endef
$(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),$(eval $(call build-template,$(p))))

.PHONY: build
build: $(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),build-$(p))


###############################################################################
### Post Build Hook
### Invokes the post-build hook in the child project if existent.
### Invoke after all services in a project have been built.
###############################################################################
define post-build-template
post-build-$(1): build-$(1)
    @if [ -e "$(1)/$(HOOK_DIR)/post-build" ]; then \
      echo "Running post-build hook script for $(1)." \
      && "$(1)/$(HOOK_DIR)/post-build"; \
    else \
      echo "No post-build hook script for $(1). Skipping."; \
    fi;
endef
$(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),$(eval $(call post-build-template,$(p))))

.PHONY: post-build
post-build: $(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),post-build-$(p))


###############################################################################
### Start
### Starts services with `docker-compose up -d`
###############################################################################
define start-template
start-$(1):
    @cd $(1) \
      && docker-compose up -d
endef
$(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),$(eval $(call start-template,$(p))))

.PHONY: start
start: $(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),start-$(p))


###############################################################################
### Post Project Start Hook
### Invokes the post-project-start hook in the child project if existent.
### Invoked after all services in a project have been started.
###############################################################################
define post-project-start-template
post-project-start-$(1):
    @if [ -e "$(1)/$(HOOK_DIR)/post-project-start" ]; then \
      echo "Running post-project-start hook script for $(1)." \
      && "$(1)/$(HOOK_DIR)/post-project-start"; \
    else \
      echo "No post-project-start hook script for $(1). Skipping."; \
    fi;
endef
$(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),$(eval $(call post-project-start-template,$(p))))

###############################################################################
### Post System Start Hook
### Invokes the post-system-start hook in the child projects if existent.
### Invoked after all services in the system have been started.
###
### Note: The final echo is required otherwise output of post-system-hook is
###       not output.
###############################################################################
define post-system-start-template
post-system-start-$(1):
    @if [ -e "$(1)/$(HOOK_DIR)/post-system-start" ]; then \
      echo "Running post-system-start hook script for $(1)." \
      && "$(1)/$(HOOK_DIR)/post-system-start" \
      && echo ""; \
    else \
      echo "No post-system-start hook script for $(1). Skipping."; \
    fi;
endef
$(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),$(eval $(call post-system-start-template,$(p))))

.PHONY: post-system-start
post-system-start: $(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),post-system-start-$(p))


###############################################################################
### Stop
### Stops services with `docker-compose stop`
###############################################################################
define stop-template
stop-$(1):
    @cd $(1) \
      && docker-compose stop
endef
$(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),$(eval $(call stop-template,$(p))))

.PHONY: stop
stop: $(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),stop-$(p))

###############################################################################
### rm
### Remove containers with `docker-compose rm`
### Does not remove volumes.
###############################################################################
define rm-template
rm-$(1):
    @cd $(1) \
      && docker-compose rm --stop --force
endef
$(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),$(eval $(call rm-template,$(p))))

.PHONY: rm
rm: $(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),rm-$(p))

###############################################################################
### Clean
### Clean services with `docker-compose rm`
### Removes all containers, volumes and local networks.
###############################################################################
define clean-template
clean-$(1):
    @cd $(1) \
      && docker-compose down -v --rmi local --remove-orphans
endef
$(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),$(eval $(call clean-template,$(p))))

.PHONY: clean
clean: $(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),clean-$(p)) network-remove

###############################################################################
### Destroy
### Deletes project directories after removing running containers.
### WARNING: This is extremely destructive. It will remove local project
###          directories. Any work that is not pushed to a remote git
###          repository will be lost!
###
###############################################################################
define destroy-template
destroy-$(1): clean
    @rm -Rf $(1)
endef
$(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),$(eval $(call destroy-template,$(p))))

.PHONY: destroy
destroy: network-remove $(foreach p,$(SUBPROJECTS),destroy-$(p))

###############################################################################
### Dynamically list all targets.
### See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26339924
###############################################################################
.PHONY: list
list:
    @$(MAKE) -pRrq -f $(MAKEFILE_LIST) : 2>/dev/null | awk -v RS= -F: '/^# File/,/^# Finished Make data base/ {if ($$1 !~ "^[#.]") {print $$1}}' | sort | egrep -v -e '^[^[:alnum:]]' -e '^$@$$' | xargs -n 1
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

Run the make file in a gitbash terminal or wsl2. The problem is that the make file doesn't convert the commands in it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have got an alternat solution to install/run reaction-commerce on windows platform. Using `npm` and `reaction-cli`.

https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/docs/next/installation-windows

Still I'm looking for the solution / fix with docker.