# use string command to chid process

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I want to use the following string and put it into childprocess

```
make -qp | awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}' | sort -u
```

I was able to run it on the terminal succesfully however when I put it for child process I got error:

I try like this

```
let commandLine = "make -qp | awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}' | sort -u";
    try {
        let { stdout, stderr } = await exec(commandLine, { cwd: workspaceRoot });
```

any idea ?

error :

```
awk: nonterminated character class ^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#
 source line number 1
 context is
     >>> /^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#/ <<<
```

this is the idea...
[How do you get the list of targets in a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219255/how-do-you-get-the-list-of-targets-in-a-makefile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash is [terminated at JS string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Using_special_characters_in_strings), so instead of `\/` is only `/` passing through.

Use:

- Double backslash `\\\/` in string.
- Wrap string into [raw backticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Raw_strings).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals