# Compgen and make: is there a way to compgen the make recipes?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make, bash-completion, compgen

I am running `compgen -c make`  in BASH on mac and am getting the following return values:

```
makepqg
makepqg
makepqg
make
makeinfo
makepqg
makepqg
```

But what I want and should? be getting (and do get when  completing) is:

```
foo
bar
biz
baz
```

Which represent my various PHONY make rules that do automatic things.

---

How does one generate this list from the SHELL, generally, with the executable tool `compgen`?

(this is the ideal question because, from python3, `subprocess` is not able to simulate the  interaction, and I'll have to do something more involved)

---

This is different than the duplicate candidate, "How do I get the targets in make (paraphrased)" in that I don't think the (non-working) command is a good answer, and this question is about `compgen` and `make` rather than `make` and the inner workings of `make`:

```
make -p no_targets__ 
| awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^\$$#\/\\t=]*:([^=]|$$)/ {split(\$$1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}' "
| grep -v '__\$$' "
| sort
```

But can I get to some kind of a solution for my high level purpose using regexes?

In my opinion, no, because compgen is easy and memorable, whereas this kludge is hard and introduces drag on any code I'd pile on top.

---

Also, the duplicate allows for changes to be made to the makefile.

In my case, the make file must be considered a given, or what I am doing will be less useful.

So, more specifically, given **any** makefile, is there a solution involving tools outside of make that can look into make and get make to output a list of its recipes as it would for bash completion.

In other words: can this be done for **ANY** makefile (without loss of generality) without requiring write permissions on the makefile, and without simulating the tab-tab using a tty simulator?

Comment: I'm not sure you can achieve what you want with a mere "shell completion tool", i.e., you'll probably need to rely on the domain specific language of `make`, e.g. like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26339924/9164010) (?)

Comment: @ErikMD I did copy that long regex and specialized it to make.  I guess if "whatever works" is the standard, then it works.

Comment: The regex has to be debugged for the awk/gawk I've got on the Mac. So, not sure whether it works either.

Comment: If your actual question is "now do I debug this Awk script" then by all means ask _that_ instead.

Comment: @tripleee No, that is not the question.  Awk is my first language and I've written entire programs in it, as I had to post process 3d models with a text processor.  But a scribble scrabble bundle of regexes is never a valid answer if you want to implement something that is clean, nice, and amounts to something like the "right way".  Instead of the squirrels nest, I added a known prefix to the rules I dynamically expose.  But it is still the wrong answer: the right answer should be simple.  I'd rather emulate tab tab than put the accepted answer in my code.

Comment: I don't disagree with that; but then isn't the correct solution to post a better answer to that question?

Comment: @tripleee Good point.  I'm thinking you can execute the tab tab emulation with expect, and I'll post that answer in a bit when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Just a gist of it.

```sh
_make_phony() {
    COMPREPLY=( )
    # a lot of code
    COMPREPLY=( foo bar biz baz )
}
complete -F _make_phony make
```

Now when you type `make` <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> you'll get:

```
foo
bar
biz
baz
```

Of course you'll have to parse the Makefile to extract the real PHONY, and also handle each possible option of `make`, like `make -f Makefile.osx` and others; it can really become complex.

Comment: Instead of this, I prefixed my rules with a simple to match pattern.  There must be an easy way, or then perhaps the answer is: open up the expect, tcl or pty and emulate the user hitting tab twice.