# How to list all Rails 3 rake tasks? rake -T seems incomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is rake db:migrate:reset not listed in rake -T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951514/why-is-rake-dbmigratereset-not-listed-in-rake-t)

Inside my Rails (3.1.3) application, I can run `rake db:test:prepare`. But when I run `rake -T [db]`, that task (and many others I can use) does not show up.

How do I get a complete list of tasks, or why is it incomplete in the first place?

E.g. http://mindspill.net/computing/cross-platform-notes/ruby-on-rails/how-to-list-rake-tasks/ shows that the 'db:test:prepare' task got listed for an older Rails version when running `rails -T`.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

I found at [Why is rake db:migrate:reset not listed in rake -T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951514/why-is-rake-dbmigratereset-not-listed-in-rake-t) (thanks @Beerlington for the link) that `rake -P` lists all tasks, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: `rake -h` displays all the rake options

Comment: Works for Capistrano 3 too: `cap -P`

Answer (score 46):

Only tasks with descriptions set will appear in `rake -T`.

As for why not all tasks have descriptions.... that I don't know.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much, but was not sure.

Comment: I think it's cause sometimes they're only marginally useful for developers, are mostly called from other tasks, etc, so they're made
 'hidden'